# Using TailwindCSS in WebStorm, the :not selector reports an error

Tags: webstorm

Using Tailwind in WebStorm, I used the not selector, which works normally, but WebStorm marked `:not` red and said I didn't know the selector. What's the matter?

[image]

Tailwind version is 2.1.4 and WebStorm version is 2021.2.3

Comment: can't reproduce in 2022.1 and 2021.3 using similar syntax; did you check if it works for you in current IDE version?

Comment: I tried. I think it's the problem of tailwindcss configuration, because I found the same problem with pseudo class selectors such as last child today